# How to generate bulk graphics using R

Tags: r, dataset, visualization, data, excel

I have a dataset of Key Performance Indicator (KPI) and for each KPI I have a current level of achivement and 2 targets : Target1 and Target2.

How can I automatically generate one graphic for each achievement as in the file attached [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z3xyxu3cnf46dzp/KPI%20R.xlsx?dl=0).

As I have many KPIs I would like to generate my graphics in a batch process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this. I guess the easiest would be to create a function that saves a bar chart for your KPI to a file:

```
save_KPI_plot <- function(fn, kpi_data) {
    png(paste0(fn, ".png"))
    # Plot code
    dev.off()
}
```

You can call the function either as follows,

```
save_KPI_plot("kpi_1", kpi_1_data)
```

or store your file names in one list and your data in another and loop over both:

```
kpi_fns <- list("filename_1", "filename_2")
kpi_data <- list(kpi_1_data, kpi_2_data)
for (i in seq_along(kpi_fns)) {
    save_KPI_plot(kpi_fns[i], kpi_data[i])
}
```

If you prefer to have a different image format you can change `png()` to `bmp()` or `jpeg()`.